# iphone webview does not response until I hold on for about half a second

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, css

I created a web view in my iPhone app but every first time I open it (on my real device), I have to tap on the screen and hold on for about half a second, then the app can response to my touch events.

I don't know if this is some kind of mechanism or is something wrong with my code.

(I use this web view to load some complex JavaScript and HTML, is there any CSS property or something else that could fix this problem?)

Comment: I think you will need to add some detail to your question to get a useful answer. There is no inherit problem with the UIWebView, so (as you suspect) this is probably something to do with the content your are putting in the view.

Comment: @Cannonade, what else should I offer for diagnosing? The script is big. But I met a problem before: I added a click event to a DIV and the DIV has a mask when you click on it. Then I solved this with a CSS property: -webkit-tap-highlight-color. I don't know if this will be an issue like that

Comment: Are you able to load the same content in Safari on your desktop or Safari on the phone?  Do you see any errors there?

Comment: Are you sure you have to tap it for half a second and not just wait for a moment? If that is true, the UIWebView might jut be loading the code.